# Python Regular Expressions with possibility that no data for some declared parameters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to parse a one-liner email data with the following email below:

> Name: Configure the system Task: System Configuration Note: Finish by
>   two weeks Task_ID: 2111

I tried the regex parsing with this python code with import re:

```
import re

raw_email = '''Name: Configure the system Task: System Configuration Note: Finish by two weeks Task_ID: 2111'''

data = re.findall(r'Name\: (.*) Task\: (.*) Note\: (.*) Task_ID\: (\d+)', raw_email)

data
[('Configure the system', 'System Configuration', 'Finish by two weeks', '2111')]
```

I have successfully parsed the data. Now what if along the email, there is missing data. For example, Task has no data as seen below:

```
import re

raw_email = '''Name: Configure the system Task: Note: Finish by two weeks Task_ID: 2111'''

data = re.findall(r'Name\: (.*) Task\: (.*) Note\: (.*) Task_ID\: (\d+)', raw_email)

data
[]
```

No data has been parsed.

Comment: Your first example doesn't parse the data given. Use the correct examples. `.` matches one character, `.*` matches any number of characters, including no character at all. Also spaces are significant, so if your data doesn't include two spaces, don't separate the `.` with two spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. As @rubystallion noted in the comment, spaces are significant:

```
data = re.findall(r'Name\:(.*)Task\:(.*)Note\:(.*)Task_ID\: (\d+)', raw_email)
```

will yield

```
[(' Configure the system ', ' ', ' Finish by two weeks ', '2111')]
```

Comment: Hi Alex, what if there is no data in Task_ID also?. I tried simulating to also remove the last variable which is the Task_ID and now it can't parse the data. Also if I make it Task_ID\:(.*), it is now parsing the next special character which should not.

Comment: Post the whole example

Comment: This is the data:
Name: Configure the system Task: System Configuration Note: Finish by two weeks Task_ID: <br><br>\r

there's no data in the Task_ID, then when I run these:                                                                          data = re.findall(r'Name\:(.*)Task\:(.*)Note\:(.*)Task_ID\:(.*)', raw_email)

it will yield to: 
[(' Configure the system ', ' ', ' Finish by two weeks ', '<br><br>\r')]

It should not capture the <br><br>\r. 

If I make it:

data = re.findall(r'Name\:(.*)Task\:(.*)Note\:(.*)Task_ID\: (\d+)', raw_email)

the output is:
[]

Comment: how about this: ```data = re.findall(r'Name\:(.*)Task\:(.*)Note\:(.*)Task_ID\: (\d*)', str)```. This means you would only accept digits for a task id